# Lectura y escritura de archivos XML desde Java

Tags: java, xml

Tengo un archivo xml en el que tengo que escribir cosas y despues leerlas.
La parte de la lectura la hago de la siguiente forma y me funciona bien:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TicketBai ... >
<Sujetos>
        <Emisor>
            <NIF>123456789</NIF>
            <ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>P</ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>
        </Emisor>
        <Destinatarios>
            <IDDestinatario>
                <NIF>987654321</NIF>
                <ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>San</ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>
            </IDDestinatario>
            <IDDestinatario>
                <NIF>987654322</NIF>
                <ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>Zar</ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>
            </IDDestinatario>
            <IDDestinatario>
                <NIF>987654333</NIF>
                <ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>Gom</ApellidosNombreRazonSocial>
            </IDDestinatario>
        </Destinatarios>
    </Sujetos>
</TicketBai>
```

Lectura del XML:

```
// Sujetos
        List<Element> list2 = root.getChildren("Sujetos");        
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
            Element sujetosElement = list2.get(i);
            List<Element> valores_sujetos = sujetosElement.getChildren();
            //System.out.println(valores_sujetos);
            //System.out.println("Pasamos al for 2...");

            for (int j = 0; j < valores_sujetos.size(); j++) {
                Element campo2 = valores_sujetos.get(j);                               
                
                if (j == 0){                    
                    String nifemisorString = campo2.getChildTextTrim("NIF");
                    campo2.setText("456456456"); // Escribir
                    System.out.println("\t" + nifemisorString);
                    String apellidoemisorString = campo2.getChildTextTrim("ApellidosNombreRazonSocial");
                    System.out.println("\t" + apellidoemisorString);
                    
                } else {                    
                    List<Element> valores_destinatario = campo2.getChildren();
                    for (int k = 0; k < valores_destinatario.size(); k++) {                    
                        Element campo2_2 = valores_destinatario.get(k);
                        String nifdeString = campo2_2.getChildTextTrim("NIF");
                        System.out.println("\t" + nifdeString);
                        String apellidodestString = campo2_2.getChildTextTrim("ApellidosNombreRazonSocial");
                        System.out.println("\t" + apellidodestString);
                } 
                }                   
            }
        }
```

Resultado:

123456789
P
987654321
San
987654322
Zar
987654333
Gom

El problema lo tengo a la hora de escribir en los campos. He tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente manera: `campo2.setText("456456456");`, se puede ver esta línea en el codigo de lectura también. Pero no se cambia nada en el xml. Alguien sabe por que no consigo cambiar el texto?

Comment: Donde estas haciendo el save del archivo?...podes mostrar esa parte por favor?

Comment: No estoy haciendo ningún save. Como debería de hacer eso?